# Active page link not getting class assigned

Tags: menus, css, navigation

I'm having problems with one of my menu items on http://itsnwa.com/ - When you enter the site, 'Work' should be bold and underlined, the same happens if you go to '50mm', but on 'Findings' this doesn't work..

Have you guy's seen anything like this before? Any help would be appreciated. And let me know If I need to post some code.

Nichlas.

Answer (score 0):

I edited your title so as not to give the impression this is a CSS issue - because it isn't. Is this a custom created menu item? If so, you may need to add the trailing slash in menu admin.

Comment: Ok, thank you! It's added as a page to the navigation, the same way I added 'Work' and '50mm': https://www.dropbox.com/s/9ry500dwmv7rdlg/Screenshot%202014-11-10%2009.48.12.png?dl=0

Comment: Then this is perplexing indeed. Try changing to a standard theme and see if the current-menu-item class is assigned then. Likewise with plugins - deactivate and try again. The only other thing I can think of is some weird conflict - do you have a CPT called findings maybe?

Comment: Yes, I have a CPT called findings, but I also got CPT's for work and 50mm..

Comment: did you see my comment above? Yes, I have a CPT called findings. But I also have CPT's for 50mm and work as well..